# Why does my Yajra Datatables have problem when adding an attribute "selected" in dropdown select?

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I have a problem with my Yajra Datable. I have a dropdown yearlist, I tried using for and foreach but it messes up the design of the datatable. when I tried hard coding it it seems to be okay lets say I have a yearlist from 2019 until 2022 but when I remove 2020 it also messes up, when I add `selected` on one of the options it also messes it up. Here is my code

blade.php

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="pull-left mb-2">
                <a class="btn btn-info" onClick="add()" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-car-alt"></i> Create
                    Travel
                    Order</a>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                <select class="form-control" id="year" name="selectedYear">
                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                    <option value="2020">2020</option>
                    <option value="2021">2021</option>
                    <option value="2022" selected>2022</option>
                    <option value="2023">2023</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid py-2" style="overflow-y: auto;height: calc(84vh - 48px); position: relative;top: 0;">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="travel-order">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Travel Order #</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Travel Date</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Controller.php

```
public function travelOrder()
    {
        return view('pages.travel-order');
    }


    public function selectYear(Request $request)
    {
        $data = DB::table('table1')
            ->where('DateYear', trim($request->year));
        if ($request->ajax()) {
        return DataTables::of($data)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
                if ($row->Remarks == "Cancelled") {
                    $buttonName = "Undo";
                    $class = "btn-warning";
                    $fa = "undo-alt";
                    $onclick = "undo";
                    $disabled = "disabled";
                } else {
                    $buttonName = "Cancel";
                    $class = "btn-danger";
                    $fa = "ban";
                    $onclick = "cancelled";
                    $disabled = "";
                }
                $button =
                '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="' . $row->id . '" data-toggle="tooltip" onClick="editFunc(' . $row->id . ')" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-success ' . $disabled . '">
                <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                    Edit
                </a>&nbsp;
                <button type="button" ' . $disabled . ' id="' . $row->id . '" data-toggle="tooltip" onClick="printFunc(' . $row->id . ')" data-original-title="Print" class="print btn btn-primary">
            <i class="fas fa-print"></i> Print
        </button>';
                return $button;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->make(true);

            return view('pages.travel-order');
        }
    }
```

Script

```
//POPULATE DATATABLE
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var TOTable = $('#travel-order').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ route('page.year.select') }}",
                method: "GET",
                data: function(d) {
                    d.year = $('#year').val();
                },
            },
            columns: [{
                    data: 'TravelOrderno',
                    name: 'TravelOrderno',
                    searchable: true
                },
                {
                    data: 'Fullname',
                    name: 'Fullname',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: true
                },
                {
                    data: 'Remarks',
                    name: 'Remarks',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false
                },
                {
                    data: 'FromDate',
                    name: 'FromDate',
                    searchable: false
                },
                {
                    data: 'action',
                    name: 'action',
                    orderable: false
                },
            ],
            order: [
                [1, 'desc']
            ]
        });
        //SELECT YEAR
        $("#year").on("change", function() {
            if ("" != $(this).val()) {
                TOTable.draw();
            }
        });
    });
```

I haven't encountered any error with this, it just that it messes up the datatable design.
below is the image of the messed up design:
[image]

This is the one that isn't messed up:
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8BT2.png]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem but made a temporary solution to it. It was because there isn't any data available for 2022 which is when it is selected first it messes up the design when selecting the previous years. My solution is I first counted my `first query` if it has rows then used `if else` statement when it has rows used the year selected but if its empty it will go back to the previous year and display the data's of the previous year and it will not messed up the design when selecting previous years or 2022. It might be also on how it draws the table. I tried using reload but its just the same.